# How do I use MVVM with bound service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm, android-architecture-lifecycle

I have a bound service that is started as foreground service for handling exoplayer.

Here is how my fragment handles the service -

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AudioPlayerFragment: Fragment() {

    private var binding: AudioPlayerFragmentBinding by autoCleared()

    private lateinit var podcast: Podcast

    private lateinit var podcastPlayerService: PodcastPlayerService
    private var isBound = false

    private val connection = object: ServiceConnection {

        override fun onServiceConnected(p0: ComponentName?, iBinder: IBinder?) {

            val binder = iBinder as PodcastPlayerService.LocalBinder
            podcastPlayerService = binder.getService()
            isBound = true

            initPlayer()
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(p0: ComponentName?) {

            isBound = false
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = AudioPlayerFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        podcast = arguments?.getParcelable(ExtrasKeyAndValues.KEY_PODCAST)!!
        binding.title.text = podcast.title
        binding.description.text = podcast.description
        startPodcastPlayerService(podcast)

        binding.exoPlayerView.useController = true
        binding.exoPlayerView.showController()
        binding.exoPlayerView.controllerAutoShow = true
        binding.exoPlayerView.controllerHideOnTouch = false
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        Intent(activity, PodcastPlayerService::class.java).also {
                intent -> activity?.bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
        initPlayer()
    }

    override fun onStop() {

        activity?.unbindService(connection)
        isBound = false

        super.onStop()
    }

    private fun initPlayer() {
        if (isBound) {
            val player: SimpleExoPlayer = podcastPlayerService.getPlayerInstance()
            binding.exoPlayerView.player = player
        }
    }

    private fun startPodcastPlayerService(podcast: Podcast) {
        val intent = Intent(context, PodcastPlayerService::class.java)
        val serviceBundle = Bundle()
        serviceBundle.putParcelable(ExtrasKeyAndValues.KEY_PODCAST, podcast)
        intent.putExtra(ExtrasKeyAndValues.BUNDLE_PODCAST_SERVICE, serviceBundle)
        context?.let { Util.startForegroundService(it, intent) }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the service (obviously) restarts when the phone is rotated (config change). How do I architect my app in a way that the service is not restarted but just attaches itself to the fragment and its UI?

Placing it in a `ViewModel` does not make sense because it is recommended to avoid putting android framework related stuff in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing here to create something like `VideoHelper` class that will include all player related code and initialization. Includes the function that will control the state of the player and other related things. Referring to your question `service is not restarted but just attaches itself to the fragment and its UI` as I remember I implemented the logic that saved the state and progress of the video in `onPause` or `onStop` and set it back when `onResume`. Basically, you need to create in separate `VideoHelper` functions like `getProgress` and call it in `onPause` or `onStop` and function `setProgress` that you should call from `onResume` and before setting it check if it not empty or null. The progress you can save any way you want - shared preferences or some static data or anything else.

Comment: I'm using exoplayer to stream audio; I'm assuming your logic will apply to that too.

Comment: @krtkush yeah it does not matter. just divide it in layers i mentioned. if you find my answer helpful please mark it as an answer)))